# Как удалить ячейку с определенным значением

Tags: javascript, html

Есть таблица и если в какой то из строк цифровое значение меньше 100, то нужно выпилить всю строку. Я взял таблицу по айдишнику и попытался перебрать ее и найти все значения меньше 100 с последующим удалением, но не выходит желаемый результат. Как исправить, что бы удалились строки где цифровое значение < 100?

```
<body>
    <table id="statsTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Дима</td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Олег</td>
            <td>140</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Андрей</td>
            <td>115</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Николай</td>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Костя</td>
            <td>80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Руслан</td>
            <td>90</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Оливер</td>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
       
        var table = document.getElementById('statsTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');
        for (var i =0; i < table.length; i++) {
            if(table[i] < 100) {
                table.remove()
            } else {
                console.log('OK');
            }
        }


    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: вы в `table` получили набор строк. Далее вам проверять надо значения второй ячейки этой строки, а у вас почему то просто `table[i] < 100` проверяется.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// объявляем таблицу
const table = document.getElementById('statsTable');

// объявляем из таблицы строки
let tableRows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');

//объявляем индекс
let index = 0;

while (index < tableRows.length) {
  // смотрим если текст в строке в последнем теге td меньше 100, то удаляем по этому индексу
  if (tableRows[index].getElementsByTagName('td')[1].innerText < 100) {
    table.deleteRow(index);
    // обновляем список строк
    tableRows = table.getElementsByTagName('tr');
  } else {
    index++;
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="statsTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Дима</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Олег</td>
    <td>140</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Андрей</td>
    <td>115</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Николай</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Костя</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Руслан</td>
    <td>90</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Оливер</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var td = $("#statsTable").find("tr").find("td:eq(1)");

for(var i=0;i<td.length;i++) {
  if(Number($(td[i]).val()) < 100) {
     
     $(td[i]).closest("tr").remove();
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="statsTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Дима</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Олег</td>
    <td>140</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Андрей</td>
    <td>115</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Николай</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Костя</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Руслан</td>
    <td>90</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Оливер</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]